# Pass Managed Object Context from a ViewController to TarBarViewController using prepare for segue

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, segue

I am trying to pass the Core Data Managed Object Context from a ViewController (which is able to load the same from AppDelegate to a TabBarViewController.

AppDelegate.m

```
// Pass the managed object context to the root view controller (the login view)
LoginViewController *rootViewController = (LoginViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
rootViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

LoginViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"LoginSegue"]){
        UITabBarController *tabBarViewController = (UITabBarController *) [segue destinationViewController];
        ReceiptsListViewController *receiptsListViewController = (ReceiptsListViewController *) [[tabBarViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:5];
        receiptsListViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    }
}
```

When i run it i encounter this error

```
2012-03-09 01:47:03.723 Peets[22893:fb03] -[UINavigationController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d91900
2012-03-09 01:47:03.747 Peets[22893:fb03] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:shouldInsertText:replacingDOMRange:givenAction: delegate: <NSInvalidArgumentException> -[UINavigationController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d91900
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand exactly how you want to pass the MOC from a VC to a TBVC. Usually the RootViewController is the TBVC. If this is your case too you pass the MOC like this:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = _managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = _persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UITabBarController *tabController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[[tabController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    MasterViewController *controller = (MasterViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[[tabController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
    controller = (MasterViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    navigationController = (UINavigationController *)[[tabController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2];
    controller = (MasterViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    return YES;
}
```

BTW: This example is based on the Master-Detail Application templante in Xcode. By default it has no TBVC, but if you add an TBVC like in the screenshot the code above will work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set the NSManagedObjectContext on UINavigationController.

`ReceiptsListViewController *receiptsListViewController = (ReceiptsListViewController *) [[tabBarViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:5]`
is your problem as it returns the UINavigationController.